Why subscribing to observable in lifecycle hook displays wrong data on page refresh for short period?
I have a problem with subscribing to an observable within a component lifecycle hook. The content is displayed correctly in the template. However changing the DOM via component method gives weird result on page refresh; the value before DOM manipulation is displayed for short period (ignoring the conditional statement in the template) and afterwards displays the data correctly.
For some reason it is working correctly, when the subscription is triggered by a method e.g. click event on an element <p (click)="changeContent()">initial content</p>. I´m using Angular v17 in development mode (ng serve).
components code
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { delay, of } from "rxjs";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dummy',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './dummy.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dummy.component.sass'
})
export class DummyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  displayValue: boolean = true;
  showExtraContent: boolean = false;
  subscription;


  constructor(
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
   ){}

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("init");
  };
  
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("view init");
    this.sub();
  }

  sub(){
    let obs = of(1,4,6,9,10);
    this.subscription = obs.pipe(delay(500)).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.displayValue = false;
        this.showExtraContent = true;
      },
      err => {},
      () => {

      }
    );
  }

  removeContent($event: any){
    $event.target.remove();
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }

  changeContent(){
    this.sub();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.subscription){
      this.subscription.unsubscribe(); 
    }
  }

}


template code
@if(displayValue){
    <p (click)="changeContent()">initial content</p>
}@else{
    <p id="modified-content">modified content</p>
    @if(showExtraContent){
        <p (click)="removeContent($event)">Additional Content (Click to remove)</p>
    }
}

<p (click)="changeContent()">Change content</p>


To illustrate the behavior I have the following gif showing on page refresh subscriptions works as expected, but as soon as the DOM is changed an additional page refresh shows old state for short period.
page refresh after changing dom
Any guidance to this problem is appreciated.

issue not reproducible stackblitz please modify the stackblitz and share back with the issue happening

I have set up a reproducible stackblitz. Removing the element and refreshing the page displays wrong content for short period.

After further tests and research, I discovered that this behavior seems to be caused by enabling server-side-rendering. After disabling ssr, it worked as expected.
If somebody knows the exact reason I would like to hear the explanation.

First of all, I dont think you need this.subscription in this case. Just subscribing to the observable should be enough.
Answering your question, when the page is reloaded angular will take the default values (displayValue = true, showExtraContent = false) until the observable is resolved, which happens asynchronously.
So, what I would do is add a isLoading attribute as follows:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { delay, of } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  displayValue: boolean = true;
  showExtraContent: boolean = false;
  isLoading: boolean = true;

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("[LOG] init");
    this.sub();
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("[LOG] view init");
  }

  sub(){
    let obs = of(1,4,6,9,10);

    obs.pipe(delay(500)).subscribe( {
      next: (res) => {
        this.displayValue = false;
        this.showExtraContent = true;
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log("[LOG] complete");
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    });
  }

  removeContent($event: any){
    this.showExtraContent = false;
  }

  changeContent(){
    this.sub();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
  }
}

@if(!isLoading) {
  @if(displayValue) {
    <p (click)="changeContent()">initial content</p>
  }@else{
    <p id="modified-content">modified content</p>
    @if(showExtraContent) {
      <p (click)="removeContent($event)">Additional Content (Click to remove)</p>
    }
  }

  <p (click)="changeContent()">Change content</p>
}

This has the con that the component does not show anything until the response returns. You have to choose between having a default value or hiding things until response returns. There is no other option as angular cannot know the value until it resolves, which takes time.
Also, I would recommend using *ngIf instead of @if, a more modern way of using ifs in templates:
<div *ngIf="!isLoading">
  <p *ngIf="displayValue" (click)="changeContent()">initial content</p>
  <p *ngIf="!displayValue" id="modified-content">modified content</p>
  <p *ngIf="!displayValue && showExtraContent" (click)="removeContent($event)">Additional Content (Click to remove)</p>
  <p (click)="changeContent()">Change content</p>
</div>

Hope this helps.
